# JWT Authentication on page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm using JWT authentication in my node site with passport and am not sure I am understanding the concepts.

Say I'm an authenticated user with my token saved in local storage. Say I then navigate to a /user page, which will display data about my user. Normally, I would check if the user is logged in, and if they are not, they would get redirected to a login page. But in this case, since I can't send the authentication token from a page request, I have to load my /user page, then the page makes a request for user data, and if the data is not found, I redirect them to the login page via javascript.

Am I correct in how I would handle this? It seems like a bad user experience, having to wait and redirect twice. Is there a way around this? Is JWT just not what I'm looking for my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the page **server side**, you should set the JWT as a cookie instead of using local storage. You would be able to catch, verify and use it when a user request a page.

But I have to say that modern web applications use **client side rendering**. So there's no need to store the JWT as a cookie. When requesting a page, you will recieve only the static assets and you will get data by queryng an API that could response with 401 (Invalid or Expired Or Missing Token).

It seems you were using server side rendering before. Now you want to use JWT and you have read somewhere that a common practice is to store it in LocalStorage (that's true). Now you are dealing with a server side rendered application architecture while tryng to mix client side rndered applications concepts.
You are not doing huge errors, but you should consider to fully render your application server or client( I suggest ) side. For the second option, google "Build single page application"

Comment: See, now I would agree with you that client side rendering is the way to go, and I use this pastern almost everywhere, but not to the extreme of being a one page application. The scenario I detailed is really one of the only ones I can think of, authenticating before rendering a user page just makes sense to me.

Comment: authenticating before rendering makes sense with server side rendering, not with client side rendering. With client side rendering you will use JWT to secure an API. The static assets are not releated.

Comment: It's more like, checking if they have access to the page, static assets and all.

Comment: In general public assets are public. And the access to a specific page can be handled by client side logic and API response interpretation. Anyway I repeat, if you are interested to server side rendering, you could store and pass JWT by using a cookie, with all pro and cons